# image icon on top of the submit button

Tags: css, drupal, button, submit, html

I am working on a submit button in Drupal. I use this HTMLcode generated from PHP:

```
<div class="buttons">
    <span class="icon">
        <input type="submit" name="op" id="edit-submit-115" value="Vložiť do košíka"  class="form-submit node-add-to-cart"" />
    </span>
</div>
```

I want the button to have gradient background which is done by adding some lines in CSS.

```
background: #F47C20;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#F88E11), to(#F06015));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #F88E11, #F06015);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#f88e11', endColorstr='#f06015'
```

Now, I would like to place an image icon on TOP of the button, close to the text. I have been searching all day for some clues but couldn't find anything.

The page with the button can be found [here](http://www.vypadavanie.net/sampon-proti-vypadavaniu-vlasov-revita).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, here are two other ideas:

1. You can use multiple backgrounds: http://tinkerbin.com/revBP8If

   Note that I had to remove the IE `filter` property because it was causing the rest of the CSS to fail on Tinkerbin. Unfortunately, multiple backgrounds aren't supported by IE8 or below.
2. A more compatible alternative is to use a regular `a` link instead of an `input` submit button. You can insert an `img` and style it to look like a button, but you'll need a bit of Javascript to submit the form: http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

Comment: Thank you, is it possible to place an icon on the top of the button as in this example? http://iwebunlimited.com/iweb-tips/css-buttons-in-iweb/  Od I needed to change html to use it first? Thank you for help

Comment: Yes, you need to change the HTML and the example you linked is EXACTLY what I meant in #2. On that page, they are NOT using real `<input type="submit">` buttons, but regular `a` links and `span`s. You do NOT want to put an image ON TOP of a button, because it covers the clickable area of the button and can result in frustrated users not being able to click the button! Changing it to an `a` tag with an image INSIDE makes everything clickable.

Comment: ok I will try to change the input type and then use the solution you suggested. Thank you very much